# Bank Balance on Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, currency, finance

I want to create a *"personal finance"* app with **Flutter**.

I want to access my bank account stats from my app in order to keep track of the money I spend and/or I earn.

1. **Is that possibile?** (which I think it is 'cause other apps seem to do it)
2. **And if it is, what's the smartest & safest way?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, flutter can help you achieve this based on the following:

1. Your financial institution permits you to carry out such actions.
2. Your financial institution provides necessary API's for such developments.